# php mail function doesn't want to work

Tags: php, email, smtp

I know you've got this topic lot of times. The thing I spent all the week reading turorials from this, and other websites.
I want to make the mail function to work, but it does'nt really want. My operation system is windows 8. I use wamp as apache,and I tried all the ways to send emails through smtp. I tried gmail and yahoo. I modified the sendmail.ini and php.ini hundred times. I tried phpmailer class, what worked for a while, but when I tried to implement in a contact form, it stoped to work.Now it's not working at all :). I tried the stunnel stuff as well, nothing really happened. Now I just try to sort out a simple mail function to send an email, as first step.The page is blank. It doesn't really give any error, but I don't get the email.
These are my settings at the moment.

php.ini file:

[mail function]

; For Win32 only.

SMTP =localhost

smtp_port =25

; For Win32 only.

; http://php.net/sendmail-from

sendmail_from =myemail@gmail.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").

sendmail_path ="\""c:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

sendmail.ini file:

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=587

auth_username=myemail@gmail.com

auth_password=password

I put port number 587, this is what I saw on the last topic I read. I hoped it helps. I tried 25 and 465 as well before. 
My question is maybe sounds stupid. 
IS IT POSSIBLE , THAT MY SMTP CONNECTION CAN BE AFFECTED, BY THE OPERATION SYSTEM OR THE FIREWALL OF THE PC??
I just started to learn know php, and I cannot go forward, till I don't solve this issue. 
Thank you

Comment: On Windows, mailing with PHP is extra-hard because you have to provide an SMTP-server that allows you to mail. Additionally, using the native mail function requires you to know how to properly format a mail. I'd suggest you delay the mailing part for now and move on learning PHP better with different tasks - or replace using the native function with using a library for that. Suggestions would be Swiftmail or PHPMailer.

Comment: Yeah..I tried php mailer. It worked at the beginning sending a simple mail . But when I tried to implement it in a contact forms source, it gave me a lot of errors.
Yeah..probably I'll be trying to solve it in the next few days(just because it's annoying that I cannot do it:p) and if is not working, I will delay it for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Have yout tried using PHPMailer?
Simply download it from https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer 
and include it in your code like:

> ```
>   include ("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
>   include ("PHPMailer/class.smtp.php");
>   $subject = "your mail subject";
>   $body = "your mail body";
>   $headers = "From: " . $emailfrom;
>
>   // Send mail
>   $mail = new PHPMailer();
>   $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
>
>   // SMTP Configuration
>   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
>   $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
>   $mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";
>   $mail->Password = "your email password";            
>   //$mail->Port = 465; // optional if you don't want to use the default 
>
>   $mail->From = "emailfrom@gmail.com";
>   $mail->FromName = "name of sender";
>   $mail->Subject = $subject;
>   $mail->MsgHTML($body);
>
>   // Add as many as you want
>   $mail->AddAddress($emailto);
>
>   // If you want to attach a file, relative path to it
>   //$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");             // attachment
>
>   $response= NULL;
>   if(!$mail->Send()) {
>      $response = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
>   } else {
>      $response = "Message sent!";
>   }
> ```